# VBA Excel linkformat.SourceFullName update takes too long

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, slide

I need to take a powerpoint presentation and for each linked object in each slide, I have to rename the link and update it. This objects are references to cells to different excel files.

Doing this looping for each slide, see if it is linked and make the change takes too long, as I have 400 slides with 1-5 linked objects in it, and I have to do this with 120 different presentations, it is impossible. The line

Shape.linkformat.Sourcefullname = newlinkname

Takes a lot of time, like 15 seconds, and it is used for each linked object. I found that it is because it has to find, open and close the excel file.

I found here that the best way is do the loop for each workbook that it is opened, and Im trying to do this, and stuck in the next situation:

I have the dictionary wbDictionary with newlinkname -> Shape that has to update with that link. At this point I'm doing this

```
For Each key In wbDictionary
    
    Application.Visible = False
    Application.UserControl = True
    Position = InStr(1, key, "!", vbTextCompare)
    Filename = left(key, Position - 1)
              
    Set wbApp = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
        
    For Each oSh In wbDictionary(key)
        oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = key
        oSh.LinkFormat.Update
    Next
    
    wbApp.Close
    Set wbApp = Nothing


Next key
```

Essentially it is doing the same, for each linked object it opens the workbook needed and makes the change.
What I want to do is opening the workbook just 1 time, so I dont have to open the same notebook multiple times.

Is it any other form to make this process faster? I can't accept the time it takes to do it normally.

Thank you.

---

Comment: `For Each` loops are slow, have you tried setting up an array instead?